# How to inject UserManager into custom UserStore in ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

When I try to inject into the constructor, I get the error below. Is there something I'm doing wrong or another way to access the UserManager?

My custom UserStore:

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<IdentityUser>, IUserRoleStore<IdentityUser>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public UserStore(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    
    ......
}
```

My Startup ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddTransient<IUserStore<IdentityUser>, UserStore>();
        services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>, RoleStore>();
        services.AddTransient<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
```

Error:

> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service
> descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]':
> A circular dependency was detected for the service of type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser>'.

Answer (score 0):

The Asp.Net Identity UserManager requests an IUserStore as a dependency.

You are now trying to inject UserManager into UserStore, but UserStore is already injected into UserManager.

Hence the circular dependency issue.

You can see the IUserStore being requested in the UserManager source code: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I realize there is a circular dependency.. just wondering if I want to use UserManager in my UserStore, how do I do it?

Comment: You won't be able to.  The dependency is already implemented the other way.  UserManager provides an API for managing users and the UserStore deals with persistence.  If you are trying to access UserManager from UserStore, then I would suggest another look at your design.  Data access layer should never be accessing the business logic layer.